# Transition between two SVG react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

I have a header with Logo, on left side, page title - in the middle, and user menu, on the right. Currently I'm displaying a SVG next to each page title. For example, on page `/organizations` I display this:

[image]

After that I've added a SVG that shows when I hover on the element (it's the same SVG, but filled)

[image]

How could I make transition between these two smooth? I'm using Tailwind for styling and tried adding `transition-all` to almost every class but that sadly didn't work.

This is the code responsible for switching between the SVGs:

```
 const [hover, setHover] = React.useState(false);

 const handleMouseOver = () => {
    setHover(true);
 };
 const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setHover(false);
 };

return (
...
   <div className="w-1/2 flex justify-center">
      <Link
        to={getModuleInfo(pathname, t, organization).url}
        className="max-w-fit flex items-center gap-2"
        prefetch="intent"
      >
        <div
          className="flex items-center gap-2"
          onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        >
          <>
             {hover
              ? getModuleInfo(pathname, t, organization).logoHover
              : getModuleInfo(pathname, t, organization).logo}
          </>
          <h5 className="organizations text-md md:text-2xl font-sans font-normal text-center text-colublue-500">
            {getModuleInfo(pathname, t, organization).title}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
...
)
```

**UPD**: to make things more clear, these would be 2 SVG examples that I would like to transition between:

[image]

And this are the `<svg>` for them:

```
// Unfilled SVG
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M8.41421 2.58579C8.78929 2.21071 9.29799 2 9.82843 2H18C18.5304 2 19.0391 2.21071 19.4142 2.58579C19.7893 2.96086 20 3.46957 20 4V20C20 20.5304 19.7893 21.0391 19.4142 21.4142C19.0391 21.7893 18.5304 22 18 22H6C5.46957 22 4.96086 21.7893 4.58579 21.4142C4.21071 21.0391 4 20.5304 4 20V7.82843C4 7.29799 4.21071 6.78929 4.58579 6.41421L8.41421 2.58579Z" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M10 2V7C10 7.55228 9.55228 8 9 8H4.5" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>


// Filled SVG
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.82843 1C9.03278 1 8.26972 1.31607 7.70711 1.87868L3.87868 5.70711C3.31607 6.26972 3 7.03278 3 7.82843V20C3 20.7957 3.31607 21.5587 3.87868 22.1213C4.44129 22.6839 5.20435 23 6 23H18C18.7956 23 19.5587 22.6839 20.1213 22.1213C20.6839 21.5587 21 20.7957 21 20V4C21 3.20435 20.6839 2.44129 20.1213 1.87868C19.5587 1.31607 18.7956 1 18 1H9.82843ZM16.7071 9.29289C17.0976 9.68342 17.0976 10.3166 16.7071 10.7071L11.3738 16.0404C10.9832 16.431 10.3501 16.431 9.95956 16.0404L7.29289 13.3738C6.90237 12.9832 6.90237 12.3501 7.29289 11.9596C7.68342 11.569 8.31658 11.569 8.70711 11.9596L10.6667 13.9191L15.2929 9.29289C15.6834 8.90237 16.3166 8.90237 16.7071 9.29289Z" fill="#052141"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I suppose both svg are the same and you are using them as inline svg. In this case you can transition the fill and the stroke in css without changing from logo to logoHover

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because second SVG is a little bit different (first one is transparent on top, while second is filled) and that's why I cannot use your suggestion

Comment: Please update your question and show us the svg elements you have

Comment: done, hope this will clarify what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @MiRAY do you still need help with this question?

Comment: if your answer is different from the others, and you think it's worth to be mentioned, then sure!

Answer (score 3):

With plain CSS and SVG, you can do this with opacity and transition.

```css
.filled {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

svg:hover .filled {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="96" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M8.41421 2.58579C8.78929 2.21071 9.29799 2 9.82843 2H18C18.5304 2 19.0391 2.21071 19.4142 2.58579C19.7893 2.96086 20 3.46957 20 4V20C20 20.5304 19.7893 21.0391 19.4142 21.4142C19.0391 21.7893 18.5304 22 18 22H6C5.46957 22 4.96086 21.7893 4.58579 21.4142C4.21071 21.0391 4 20.5304 4 20V7.82843C4 7.29799 4.21071 6.78929 4.58579 6.41421L8.41421 2.58579Z" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <path d="M10 2V7C10 7.55228 9.55228 8 9 8H4.5" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <path class="filled" d="M9.82843 1C9.03278 1 8.26972 1.31607 7.70711 1.87868L3.87868 5.70711C3.31607 6.26972 3 7.03278 3 7.82843V20C3 20.7957 3.31607 21.5587 3.87868 22.1213C4.44129 22.6839 5.20435 23 6 23H18C18.7956 23 19.5587 22.6839 20.1213 22.1213C20.6839 21.5587 21 20.7957 21 20V4C21 3.20435 20.6839 2.44129 20.1213 1.87868C19.5587 1.31607 18.7956 1 18 1H9.82843ZM16.7071 9.29289C17.0976 9.68342 17.0976 10.3166 16.7071 10.7071L11.3738 16.0404C10.9832 16.431 10.3501 16.431 9.95956 16.0404L7.29289 13.3738C6.90237 12.9832 6.90237 12.3501 7.29289 11.9596C7.68342 11.569 8.31658 11.569 8.70711 11.9596L10.6667 13.9191L15.2929 9.29289C15.6834 8.90237 16.3166 8.90237 16.7071 9.29289Z" fill="#052141"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is a good example, but not quite useful in my case, since I want the transition to happen when I hover on page title, and I would need this for multiple pages

Comment: What's the markup for page title and how does it relate to the SVG? Add markup to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've added the markup for title

Comment: I'm aware of the option where I overlap two images, show first one at the beginning and on hover show the second one with `opacity` property, but I wanted to know if there would be a way to transition between rendering two components depending on the state

Comment: If you would like to stick to your code, where you render a svg depending on the state value, then it would not be possible to transition between those two. I suggest refactoring your function and use the suggestion from above (adding both `svg`, where second one should have initial `opacity` set to `0` and animate opacity property on hover

Answer (score 2):

You could also use css variables to transition between the design states.

Similar to @ksav's this approach will also need to combine both svgs.
This way we can render the icon with more design variations.

```js
let icon = document.querySelector('.iconTrans');

function toggleState() {
  icon.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 10em;
}

svg path {
  transition: 1s;
}

.iconTrans {
  --strokeColor: #052141;
  --strokeWidth: 2px;
  --opacity1: 1;
  --opacity2: 0;
  --fillColor: #052141;
}

.active {
  --strokeColor: #052141;
  --strokeWidth: 0px;
  --opacity1: 0;
  --opacity2: 1;
  --fillColor: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="btnToggle" onclick="toggleState()">Toggle state</button></p>
<svg class="iconTrans" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="paper" d="M8.41421 2.58579C8.78929 2.21071 9.29799 2 9.82843 2H18C18.5304 2 19.0391 2.21071 19.4142 2.58579C19.7893 2.96086 20 3.46957 20 4V20C20 20.5304 19.7893 21.0391 19.4142 21.4142C19.0391 21.7893 18.5304 22 18 22H6C5.46957 22 4.96086 21.7893 4.58579 21.4142C4.21071 21.0391 4 20.5304 4 20V7.82843C4 7.29799 4.21071 6.78929 4.58579 6.41421L8.41421 2.58579Z 
M10 2V7C10 7.55228 9.55228 8 9 8H4.5" style="stroke:var(--strokeColor); stroke-width:var(--strokeWidth); opacity:var(--opacity1)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  <path class="paperCheck" d="M9.82843 1C9.03278 1 8.26972 1.31607 7.70711 1.87868L3.87868 5.70711C3.31607 6.26972 3 7.03278 3 7.82843V20C3 20.7957 3.31607 21.5587 3.87868 22.1213C4.44129 22.6839 5.20435 23 6 23H18C18.7956 23 19.5587 22.6839 20.1213 22.1213C20.6839 21.5587 21 20.7957 21 20V4C21 3.20435 20.6839 2.44129 20.1213 1.87868C19.5587 1.31607 18.7956 1 18 1H9.82843Z
M16.7071 9.29289C17.0976 9.68342 17.0976 10.3166 16.7071 10.7071L11.3738 16.0404C10.9832 16.431 10.3501 16.431 9.95956 16.0404L7.29289 13.3738C6.90237 12.9832 6.90237 12.3501 7.29289 11.9596C7.68342 11.569 8.31658 11.569 8.70711 11.9596L10.6667 13.9191L15.2929 9.29289C15.6834 8.90237 16.3166 8.90237 16.7071 9.29289Z" style="fill:var(--fillColor); opacity:var(--opacity2); " />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've released [an online tool that allows you to automaticaly generate combined SVG files (like @ksav has done) in bulk](https://cawecoy.com/alternate-svg-on-hover-css/) ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/cawecoy/alternate-svg-on-hover-css)).

The tool will combine every 2 SVG files (filled and unfilled) into a single SGV file, adding the content of the "unfilled" SVG icon into a `<g class="first-icon"></g>` and the content of the "filled" SVG icon into a `<g class="second-icon"></g>`. Then you can have the hover effect in your HTML/CSS like:

```css
svg .first-icon{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
svg .second-icon{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
svg:hover .first-icon{
    opacity: 0;
}
svg:hover .second-icon{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g class="first-icon">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M8.41421 2.58579C8.78929 2.21071 9.29799 2 9.82843 2H18C18.5304 2 19.0391 2.21071 19.4142 2.58579C19.7893 2.96086 20 3.46957 20 4V20C20 20.5304 19.7893 21.0391 19.4142 21.4142C19.0391 21.7893 18.5304 22 18 22H6C5.46957 22 4.96086 21.7893 4.58579 21.4142C4.21071 21.0391 4 20.5304 4 20V7.82843C4 7.29799 4.21071 6.78929 4.58579 6.41421L8.41421 2.58579Z" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path d="M10 2V7C10 7.55228 9.55228 8 9 8H4.5" stroke="#052141" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
<g class="second-icon">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.82843 1C9.03278 1 8.26972 1.31607 7.70711 1.87868L3.87868 5.70711C3.31607 6.26972 3 7.03278 3 7.82843V20C3 20.7957 3.31607 21.5587 3.87868 22.1213C4.44129 22.6839 5.20435 23 6 23H18C18.7956 23 19.5587 22.6839 20.1213 22.1213C20.6839 21.5587 21 20.7957 21 20V4C21 3.20435 20.6839 2.44129 20.1213 1.87868C19.5587 1.31607 18.7956 1 18 1H9.82843ZM16.7071 9.29289C17.0976 9.68342 17.0976 10.3166 16.7071 10.7071L11.3738 16.0404C10.9832 16.431 10.3501 16.431 9.95956 16.0404L7.29289 13.3738C6.90237 12.9832 6.90237 12.3501 7.29289 11.9596C7.68342 11.569 8.31658 11.569 8.70711 11.9596L10.6667 13.9191L15.2929 9.29289C15.6834 8.90237 16.3166 8.90237 16.7071 9.29289Z" fill="#052141"/>
</g>
</svg>
```